# How do I bind an event captured by a XAML element to a method in an arbitrary class in C#?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

I am a C# newbie trying to build a simple MVVM app, and I am having trouble tying events in my XAML View to methods in my Model or ViewModel. I understand why MVVM is used and feel like I get the broad strokes of how to put an MVVM app together, but I am lost in the details. I apologize in advance if it looks like I have no idea what I'm doing, but I don't, despite lots of reading up on the subject.

I want btnUpdate_Click in MainScreenViewModel to execute when the button is clicked, but I get the error

> MC6005 Click="vm:btnUpdate_Click" is not valid. 'vm:btnUpdate_Click' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

If my classes are public and in the same namespace, what do I need to do to make them visible from my View? I don't want to move methods back to the MainWindow class.

```
<Window x:Class="SFM_Calculator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SFM_Calculator"
    xmlns:vm="MainScreenViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SFMModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ...
        <Button
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            x:Name="btnUpdate"
            Content="Update"
            Click="vm:btnUpdate_Click"
            />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SFM_Calculator
{
    public class MainScreenViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestInt = 999;
        }
    
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    
        public SFMModel sfmModel = new SFMModel();

        private int _testInt;

        public int TestInt
        {
            get { return _testInt; }
            set { _testInt = value; }
        }

        public MainScreenViewModel()
        {                        
            Debug.WriteLine("Got here.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SFM_Calculator
{
    public class SFMModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _tprop;

        public int TProp
        {
            get { return _tprop; }
            set { _tprop = value; }
        }

        public SFMModel ()
        {
            TProp = 69;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SFM_Calculator
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your viewModel should expose a command, not a method. Plus you should access the exposed command via binding mechanism.

Sample Command that implements required ICommand interface

```
internal class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action execute;

    public Command(Action execute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
    }
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```

Sample ViewModel that exposes ICommand (not a regular method as in your example). It will change the value of Text property after clicking the button - just to show that it works.

```
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public ICommand AwesomeCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        AwesomeCommand = new Command(() => { 
            Text = "Button clicked"; 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text))); 
        });
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding AwesomeCommand}"></Button>
    <Label Content="{Binding Text}" Height="100"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

code-behind MainWindow, to hook-up ViewModel and the view (MainWindow):

```
public MainWindow()
{
   DataContext = new ViewModel();
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz... I don't have enough rep to upvote yet.